# Is it possible to evaluate whether a class interface extends a certain base class?

Tags: java, generics

I have a method that takes a generic class interface as an argument, I would like to check that the interface provided extends a certain base class, if it does not I will throw an exception. Is it possible to do something similar to:

```
public void genericMethod(Class<T> c) {
    if (!(c instanceof baseClass)) {
        throw new Exception("Must be instance of base class");
    }
}
```

Even if it is possible, would it be considered good practice? Or should java generics follow the same principles of `ducktyping`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **[`Class.isAssignableFrom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29)**:

```
if (baseClass.isAssignableFrom(c)) {
  ...
}
```

This code assumes that `baseClass` is a variable (field, local variable, whatever) of type `Class`. If `baseClass` is the *name* of a class (which would be against Java conventions), then use `baseClass.class` instead, as suggested by Pshemo in the comments.

From the documentation:

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter.

Comment: To be more precise `baseClass.class.isAssignableFrom(c)`. Anyway +1

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. However, there's no unique, general solution: if `baseClass` is a `Class` (as I initially assumed, based on Java conventions), you must not use `.class`. If it is the *name* of a class, then you must use `.class`. To be even more precise, if `baseClass` is the name of a class, then the code I've originally written wouldn't even compile; however if it is a variable of type `Class`, then your code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Since OP used `instanceof baseClass` I assumed that `baseClass` is a name of interface rather than Class reference, but everything is possible on SO questins :)

Answer (score 3):

To address the core part of your question; while you're going the path of generics, it'll look better if you just had:

```
       public void genericMethod(Class<? extends BaseClass> c) {
          // do what you want
        }
```

The `?` wildcard character tells the compiler that only child classes of `BaseClass` are acceptable arguments, essentially performing the `instanceOf` check for you.

This pretty much eliminates the possibility of the abuse of your method during compile time

See also

- [Oracle's Generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html)